# C++, Fulfilling typedef with lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, arduino, typedef

I have a function such as:

```
typedef void(*timercallback)(void);
void timer1_attachInterrupt(timercallback userFunc);
```

I wish to call a member method rather than a C style function, so I have tried the following lambda:

```
timer1_attachInterrupt([this](void) -> void { _member_method(); });
```

However I get the compiler error:

> No suitable conversion function from "lambda [] void () -> void" to
>   "timercallback" exists

As far as I can see, the lambda has void arguments like the typedef, and returns void like the tyepdef. What am I missing?

Comment: Arundo?   If so add tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What am I missing?

The lambda creates a closure **object** since it needs to capture state. Therefore you can't just pass it where a regular function pointer is expected.

Since your API doesn't make any provisions for passing state to the callback, you will need to use something unpleasant like global variables.

If you *can* modify `timer1_attachInterrupt`<sup>1</sup>, then I suggest you allow it to accept any (type-erased) functor. `std::function` is just the utility to accomplish that:

```
using timercallback = void(void);
void timer1_attachInterrupt(std::function<timercallback> userFunc);
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>It's quite clear the OP can't after the [arduino](/questions/tagged/arduino) edit. But I leave the suggestion for anyone who may be able to modify *their* functions.</sub>

Comment: I cannot modify timer1_attachInterrupt. I did previously use global variables and had to store most of my data outside of the class. I was trying to make it a little more OO.

Comment: @uhsl_m - Your woes are purely due to poor API design. Global state it is.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I wanted to comment on the answer, but because of rep. points I can't directly.
Mine is not answer, but comment on the above  std::function<> suggestion.

You /op must really watch out: the std::function may new()/ malloc inside it's implementation. If that was me, that would be the last thing i want - any heap allocations when dealing with ISRs.  (And worse, un-controlled allocations/de-allocations due to create/destroy).

It's not worth it in what you trying todo.